# Reference a member of a structure using a variable stored in a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, microcontroller

I have three motor drivers that I would like to interface with my controller. My question deals with how to write the code to make functions to update the values for these drivers.

I use structures to represent the drivers and the controller has a built-in set of structures for accessing the different registers of the controller.

I would like to make one function that takes the structure for a specific motor driver as an input parameter and changes the values of the various GPIOs for that specific motor driver.

Lets say that a pin on my controller is accessed with the following code (this is the structure that is given by the controller manufacturer):

```
GpioCtrlRegs.GPAMUX1.bit.GPIO01 = 0;
```

To make it easy to update the pins in multiple locations at once, I use the following macros:

```
#define MOTOR1_nSLEEP       GPIO01
#define MOTOR1_nSLEEP_MUX   GPAMUX1

GpioCtrlRegs.MOTOR1_nSLEEP_MUX.bit.MOTOR1_nSLEEP = 1;
```

Now here is where it gets tricky. I would like to define the following function.

```
void Initialize (struct motor_driver MOTOR1) {
GpioCtrlRegs.MOTOR1_nSLEEP_MUX.bit.MOTOR1_nSLEEP = 1;
}
```

But the issue is that I need to be able to change the macros based upon the input parameter. To my knowledge, this is not possible. So I thought that I would use pointers to point to the GPIOs specific location in memory and then add that pointer to the "struct motor_driver" so that it gets passed into the function as well. So something like this:

```
MOTOR1.pointers.nSLEEP_MUX =  &(GpioCtrlRegs.MOTOR1_nSLEEP_MUX.bit.MOTOR1_nSLEEP);
```

And then in the function, I could just use this pointer to directly adjust the value of the GPIO register. Unfortunately, pointers aren't allowed to take a value of a bit field since they must work on the byte level.

So I would have to use the pointer for the first #define value "MOTOR1_nSLEEP_MUX" and then manually access ".bit.MOTOR1_nSLEEP" (possibly by using struct pointers).

The issue now is that I don't know how to work with the macro "MOTOR1_nSLEEP" in a flexible, macro independent way, because it is equal to "GPIO01". How do I pass "GPIO01" to the necessary structure pointer so that I can access the correct bit field? Do you have any recommendations? Am I approaching this in a dumb way in the first place?

Here is some additional info on GpioCtrlRegs:

```
struct GPIO_CTRL_REGS {
    union   GPACTRL_REG     GPACTRL;    // GPIO A Control Register (GPIO0 to 31)
    union   GPA1_REG        GPAQSEL1;   // GPIO A Qualifier Select 1 Register (GPIO0 to 15)
    union   GPA2_REG        GPAQSEL2;   // GPIO A Qualifier Select 2 Register (GPIO16 to 31)
    union   GPA1_REG        GPAMUX1;    // GPIO A Mux 1 Register (GPIO0 to 15)
    union   GPA2_REG        GPAMUX2;    // GPIO A Mux 2 Register (GPIO16 to 31)
    union   GPADAT_REG      GPADIR;     // GPIO A Direction Register (GPIO0 to 31) )
    union   GPADAT_REG      GPAPUD;     // GPIO A Pull-Up Disable Register
    Uint16                  rsvd1[2];   // Reserved
    union   GPBCTRL_REG     GPBCTRL;    // GPIO B Control Register (GPIO32 to 63)
    union   GPB1_REG        GPBQSEL1;   // GPIO B Qualifier Select 1 Register (GPIO32 to 47)
    union   GPB2_REG        GPBQSEL2;   // GPIO B Qualifier Select 2 Register (GPIO48 to 63)
    union   GPB1_REG        GPBMUX1;    // GPIO B Mux 1 Register (GPIO32 to 47)
    union   GPB2_REG        GPBMUX2;    // GPIO B Mux 2 Register (GPIO48 to 63)
    union   GPBDAT_REG      GPBDIR;     // GPIO B Direction Register (GPIO32 to 63)
    union   GPBDAT_REG      GPBPUD;     // GPIO B Pull-Up Disable Register
    Uint16                  rsvd2[24];  // Reserved
    union   AIO_REG         AIOMUX1;    // Analog IO Mux 1 Register
    Uint16                  rsvd3[2];   // Reserved
    union   AIODAT_REG      AIODIR;     // Analog IO Direction Register
    Uint16                  rsvd4[4];   // Reserved
};

union GPA1_REG {
    Uint32 all;
    struct GPA1_BITS    bit;
};

struct GPA1_BITS {     // bits description
    Uint16  GPIO0:2;            // 1:0  GPIO0
    Uint16  GPIO1:2;            // 3:2  GPIO1
    Uint16  GPIO2:2;            // 5:4  GPIO2
    Uint16  GPIO3:2;            // 7:6  GPIO3
    Uint16  GPIO4:2;            // 9:8  GPIO4
    Uint16  GPIO5:2;            // 11:10    GPIO5
    Uint16  GPIO6:2;            // 13:12    GPIO6
    Uint16  GPIO7:2;            // 15:14    GPIO7
    Uint16  GPIO8:2;            // 17:16    GPIO8
    Uint16  GPIO9:2;            // 19:18    GPIO9
    Uint16  GPIO10:2;           // 21:20    GPIO10
    Uint16  GPIO11:2;           // 23:22    GPIO11
    Uint16  GPIO12:2;           // 25:24    GPIO12
    Uint16  GPIO13:2;           // 27:26    GPIO13
    Uint16  GPIO14:2;           // 29:28    GPIO14
    Uint16  GPIO15:2;           // 31:30    GPIO15
};
```

And in another file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#pragma DATA_SECTION("GpioCtrlRegsFile")
#else
#pragma DATA_SECTION(GpioCtrlRegs,"GpioCtrlRegsFile");
#endif
volatile struct GPIO_CTRL_REGS GpioCtrlRegs;
```

Comment: You may be getting too fancy with the macros here. Have you considered making your own structure with an array of motors? As long as your structure fields cover the same memory as their structure, it will work. Remember to define with all the same extras, like volatile, packing, byte orders, whatever else may be attached to it.

Comment: Why don't you create a condition to decide what register would be initialized

Comment: Its possible to do a condition, but given how many functions there are going to be and how many times I'd have to do this (adding to code length and overhead time), I would prefer to come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit @ZanLynx? Are you suggesting I just mimic their exact structure within my motor structure? I guess this would work, but I'd have to learn how they do it exactly. And won't this use a bunch of memory? I was hoping to use pointers so I could just reference each bit field.

Comment: It's impossible to propose ideas because you're not telling us anything about `GpioCtrlRegs` or `Mode_GPIO`. Answers will be completely different  depending on how they're declared - in particular whether they're structs with bit fields. Bit fields can't have their address taken (with `&`) at all. You need to include their declarations.

Comment: I have the same problem as Gene coming up with specifics. But what I was getting at with the array suggestion is to make the motor access pins something that you can calculate. If there is one pin per motor, you find the byte then calculate the bit mask. If there's 8 per motor you use a unsigned char array. Etc. Then you don't need lookup tables. You would be able to do things like `turn_on(2)` and it would compute `base[byte] |= 1<<bit`

Comment: And as for using memory, no. What happens is that you define a structure that maps to the hardware and you access it through a pointer. That pointer might be set in the code or it might be in a linker file, but it is there somewhere. So the structure through a pointer gives you a different view of the memory but doesn't use extra memory.

Comment: I've added some details on GpioCtrlRegs and I've gotten rid of Mode_GPIO and replaced it with a just a single bit since it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The motors are connected to motor drivers, so I need to interface with around 10 different pins. The issue is that to keep the design flexible, I want to be able to change the pins on the controller that are being used without too much difficulty (be able to change the pin assignments in one code location, instead of having to jump through a bunch of different places).

Comment: The problem is that the pins are all over the place. Some are in GPAMUX1 struct, some in GPBMUX2, etc. so this first macro is important as well to determining the correct location.

Comment: @LooYung Thanks for adding the headers. My answer is based on a similar header, though not the same. The conclusion though _is_ the same. There's not a good way to touch the registers with a table of pointers as you're trying to do. Give it up and - if you really need the motor number to be a variable - write `switch` code.

Comment: Thanks @Gene. I figured it would be difficult and debatable if it would be worth the effort. Good to hear that its probably not worth it before I invest too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a [header file](http://wtbcvt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DSP2833x_headers/include/DSP2833x_Gpio.h) that's probably similar to the one you're using. The reference `GpioCtrlRegs.GPAMUX1.bit.GPIO01` is a bit field. You can't take the address of a bit field.

And I have to guess that `Mode_GPIO` is an int where only the low bit (0 or 1) matters. That's all that makes sense.

The field `GpioCtrlRegs.GPAMUX1` is a union, which has an address.

So - assuming the linked header file - you could pick between two mux'es in the same bank with a table like:

```
static union GPB1_REG *mux[2] = { &GpioCtrlRegs.GPBMUX1, &GpioCtrlRegs.GPBMUX2 };
```

Then you can touch the `i`th mux with:

```
mux[i]->bit.MOTOR1_nSLEEP = 1;
```

But that's about it. You can't even reference `GPCMUX1` or `2` in the same array because the header gives them different types.

I highly recommend you just give it up. If you really need to pick the motor with an `int`, then write functions like:

```
void motorSleep(int i) {
  switch (i):
    case 1:
      ... set the registers to make 3 sleep
      break;
    case 2:
      ... set the registers to make 2 sleep
      break;
    case 3:
      ... set the registers for all other inputs
      break;
    default:
      assert(0);
  }
}
```

The moral is not to over-engineer stuff like this. The people who designed the header file clearly intended it to be used as above, not with fancy address arithmetic. I'm not saying they did you a favor. But it is what it is.